# JPA - how to find a string list in a postgres text array

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a text array and crud operations are working well. Now, I would like to find a list of string using a native query. I've tried the following solution

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "select * from biz_db.biz_user where :skills=ANY(skills) and " +
        "expert=1 and enabled=1 and " +
        "verified=1 order by creation_date desc limit 3")
List<User> findAllExpertsBySkills(@Param("skills") String[] skills);
```

Which I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : skills
```

Any help appreciated.

here is the skills in User class

```
@Type( type = "string-array" )
@Column(
        name = "skills",
        columnDefinition = "text[]"
)
private String[] skills;
```

And in the table is defined

```
skills text[] NULL,
```

Comment: I am not sure about the Hibernate message, how you can bound an array. But from Postgres view: `:skills` seems to be an array. So you are trying to do `array = ANY(array)`. This is not supported. Maybe you could try the && operator: `:skills && skills`. This operator gives true, if both arrays overlap (share at least one element)

Comment: @S-Man I've tried that and got ''Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea && text[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.''

Comment: So it seems that `:skills`is of type bytea. I am not too deep into Hibernate but it seems that Hibernate does not support array types. Maybe this helps? https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @S-Man is the type of skills in your table? can yous show us both entity and table schema please

Comment: If `skills` contains binary data (which is what `bytea` means), then why would you search for text strings in that column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Skills is text[] in postgresql

Comment: As decribed above, I believe this is an issue with arrays and Hibernate. Did you read the linked article?

Comment: Please refer my answer in the below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695264/how-to-filter-postgres-array-column-with-the-jpa-criteria-api/66022992#66022992

Comment: Please refer my answer in the below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695264/how-to-filter-postgres-array-column-with-the-jpa-criteria-api/66022992#66022992

Comment: Please refer my comment in the below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695264/how-to-filter-postgres-array-column-with-the-jpa-criteria-api/66022992#66022992

Comment: Please refer my post in the blow one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66022992/3981611

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `Any` should be :

```
WHERE skills = ANY(:skills)
```

For more details take a look at [**9.20.4. ANY/SOME**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-subquery.html)

> expression operator ANY (array expression)

Comment: For me it seems that both sides are arrays. In this case this would not work

Comment: @S-Man why It should not work, take a look https://rextester.com/QSO46205

Comment: Yes, but I thought that the left-handed term is an array too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ef6bb2f72fefe407c813654f00679237 (I made this assumption because of the `ANY(skills)` part in the query)

Comment: @S-Man This is not clear in the question, I will ask the question

Comment: @S-Man yes, both sides are array and I've tried that where clause condition and it didn't work

Comment: @YCF_L I've updated the question and added the skills definition in java class and table.

Comment: Got this error: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly there's the use of a wrong operator. I believe what you're looking for is overlap between the two? The operator would be `&&`, making this the where clause:

```
WHERE skills && :skills
```

If you want the table field to contain all the elements from the parameter, then use the `@>` operator, as shown [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-array.html)

```
WHERE skills @> :skills
```

Now all that remains is the data type. For strings, numbers and dates, you can just add [my library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor) to your project and it will work directly. There are types for which it won't work, like `UUID`, but I haven't done extensive enough testing for others.

Comment: Both didn't work. Got  this error: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
I think the issue is because of String[] but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
where array_position(skills, :skills) > 0
```

it could be also your db mapping to entity problem,

test with @Transit for entity property

Comment: Please use code formatting/markup for your answer to improve readability