# Criteria builder for postgres jsonB ? operator

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table synonyms_table with a jsonb column synonym which is a json array.
Entries in this column will look something like this : ["good","nice","awesome"]

I have a query
select * from synonyms_table where synonym::jsonb ? 'good';

I want to create this using CriteriaBuilder.
How can I do that? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
Specification specification = (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    return criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.<String>get("synonym"), criteriaBuilder.literal("synonym")), 'good');
};
```

But this is not working
Getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_extract_path_text(character varying, character varying) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just assuming but i think the problem is that your column is a plain string array and not an array or objects or a `{..}` json.

I've checked the `jsonb_array_elements` function but the only example i could find was those of arrays having complex objects in them.

You either look for more example of this `jsonb_array_elements` and see if anything help.

Or

If you transform the column in a simple `varchar[]`

you could do something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695695/3018285